# Determining to use JedisPool with boolean variable

Tags: java, jedis, boomi, apache-commons-pool

I'm working on a custom Boomi connector that uses Jedis in order to send data to a redis server.
One thing I am trying to work on, is removing the parameter `String parameters` and still determining if I should use a pool, but I am unsure how I would go about this.

```
public RedisConnectionHandler(String hosts, String password, Integer timeout,
                              Integer retries, Boolean expiry, Integer timeToExpire, String parameters,
                              Boolean useSSL) {
    if (!isNullOrEmpty(hosts)) {
        if (hosts.contains(",")) {
            // split into new array value where there is a comma, which indicates that there are more than one
            // host to connect to
            String[] pairs = hosts.split(",");
            // set host and port in a new unique collection
            Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<>();
            for (String s : pairs) {
                // split into new array value where there is a semi-column, which contains the port
                String[] pair = s.split(":");
                // add the host and port into the collection
                jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort(pair[0], Integer.parseInt(pair[1])));
            }
            JedisCluster jedisCluster;
            if (isNullOrEmpty(password)) {
                jedisCluster = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes);
            } else {
                jedisCluster = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes, timeout, timeout, retries, password, new GenericObjectPoolConfig());
            }
            try {
                // provides information about, and dynamic access to, a single field of a class or an interface -
                // in this case connectionHandler
                Field connectionField = JedisCluster.class.getDeclaredField("connectionHandler");
                // Disable java access checks on the connectionHandler field
                connectionField.setAccessible(true);
                // use the Field class and cast it to connection handler, and get the jedis cluster
                jedisClusterConnectionHandler = (JedisClusterConnectionHandler) connectionField.get(jedisCluster);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ErrorUtils.throwException(e);
            }
        } else {
            // true if parameters is null and contains "noPool"
            noPool = isNullOrEmpty(parameters) && parameters.contains("noPool");
            // split string where any semi-column occurs
            String[] pair = hosts.split(":");
            // if noPool is true
            if (noPool) {
                // if password is not provided
                if (isNullOrEmpty(password)) {
                    // new jedis connection
                    jedis = new Jedis(pair[0], Integer.parseInt(pair[1]), timeout, useSSL);
                } else {
                    // new jedis connection, but authenticated
                    jedis = new Jedis(pair[0], Integer.parseInt(pair[1]), timeout, useSSL);
                    jedis.auth(password);
                }
            } else {
                JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
                poolConfig.setMaxTotal(poolSize);
                poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(timeout);

                if (isNullOrEmpty(password)) {
                    jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, pair[0], Integer.parseInt(pair[1]), timeout, useSSL);
                } else {
                    jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, pair[0], Integer.parseInt(pair[1]), timeout,
                            password, useSSL);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        ErrorUtils.throwException(new Exception("The redis host URL was not supplied."));
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all your naming convention is very confusing. If `noPool` parameter is provided, you have set the `isPool = true`. 

From your title i understand that you are trying to find whether to have a `JedisPool` or not based on a boolean variable. Could you please explain what is not working ?

Comment: Hi @ViswanathLekshmanan, I've changed the name from `isPool` to `noPool` as suggested. The code works, however, I want to remove the `Boolean noPool` and still determine whether the client is best to use a pool or just the basic jedis implementation

Comment: I also think I have solved my problem now. I believe, that there is no need to even use this parameter, I could set the default as using the pool, because that seems to be the common-practice.

Comment: Using JedisPool is the normal practice (It will scale up and down). However you can set the max pool size to limit the number of connections without exhausting the resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the code that determines if the parameters contain the variable `noPool` because it is wiser to use a connection pool rather than a single instance in a multi-threaded environment.

```
JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
poolConfig.setMaxTotal(poolSize);
poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(timeout);
if (isNullOrEmpty(password)) {
    jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, pair[0], Integer.parseInt(pair[1]), timeout, useSSL);
} else {
    jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, pair[0], Integer.parseInt(pair[1]), timeout,
        password, useSSL);
}
```